# How get exception,error,log for HIVE-SQOOP based Batch Job?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, sqoop, hiveql

I have Hadoop cluster with 6 datanode and 1 namenode. I have few(4) jobs in HIVE which run on every day and push some data from logfile to our OLPT data base using sqoop.  I do not have oozie installed in the environment. All are written in HIVE script file (.sql file) and I run those from unix script(.sh file). Those shell script file are attach with different OS cron job to run those on different time.

**Now Requirement is This:**

Generate log/status for each job separately on daily basis. So that at the end of the day looking into those log we can identify which job run successfully and time it took to run , which job failed and dump/stack stace for that failed job.(Feature plan is that we will have mail server and every failed or success job shell script will send mail to respective stack holder with those log/status file as attachment)

Now my problem is how I can find error/exception if anything I have to run those batch job / shell script and how to generate success log also with execution time?

I tried to get the output in text file for each query run into HIVE by redirecting the output but that is not working.

for example :

```
Select * from staging_table;>>output.txt
```

Is there any way to do this by configuring HIVE log for each and every HIVE job on day to day basis?

Please let me know if any one face this issue and how can I resolve this?

Comment: not sure but you can give a try to this approach, in `hive` you can run external system commands using `'!'` so for the `select` output try to make use of `tee`

Comment: did you find anything else? IMHO its not exactly possible except the one I suggested you...

Comment: did you find anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from staging_table;>>output.txt
```

this is Redirecting output if you are looking for that option then below is the way from the console.

```
hive -e 'Select * from staging_table' > /home/user/output.txt
```

this will simply redirect the output. It wont display job specific log information.

However, I am assuming that you are running on yarn, if you are expecting to see application(job) specific for logs  please see [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html)

***Resulting log file locations :***

During run time you will see all the container logs in the `${yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs}`

Using UI you can see the logs i.e job level and task level.

other way is to look from and dump application/job specific logs from command line.

```
yarn logs -applicationId your_application_id
```

Please note that using the `yarn logs -applicationId <application_id>` method is preferred but it does require log aggregation to be enabled first.
[Also see much better explanation here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/)

Comment: Thanks.... yes you are right redirection will give the output of SQL only , not the job status and execution time information.... "yarn logs -applicationId your_application_id" in this approach problem is that all are running in back end OS cron job on different time of the day (now on every 6 hours) , so I will never know about the application id (will change every execution) . Do you think I can resolve the issue in oozie? I do not have much knowledge in oozie. Pls help...

Comment: I have no idea with oozie. but all the previous job logs are maintained in job history server right. Can you find it there ? there are 2 things from ui first one currently running job second one is history jobs. in any case we can see the job/task tracker logs with all metrics.

Comment: we have same cron style jobs which were running. Thats the only way to see job specific logs to see.